# Force a reference to be absolute using Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

When adding a reference to a web application project in VS (2008 in this case), the "hintpath" in the csproj file is being created as a relative reference.  Is there a way (using the GUI, not manually editing the file) to make this an absolute reference (i.e. C:\Temp\DllName.dll)?

The issue I am running into is when seperate build machines have a different working directories for the project.  When the reference is relative, and the referenced dll is not within the project working directory, the relative reference may not point to the same location on both machines.

Comment: What is the purpose for wanting a non-relative path? I could understand wanting a path that includes a SpecialFolder, but an entirely hard-coded path is inflexible across systems.

Comment: @Yoooder You haven't seen the hilarious relative paths visual studio likes to use, it may as well be hard coded.   I've seen them ..\..\ themselves all the way up to the root and then back to the target folder, it's great.

Comment: I was looking for this. Why? I have a few extension methods that recover from breaking changes in the various versions of the app over the years. Thank you AutoDesk. Wait, no. These Extension methods are universal in all my apps. I don't want to have to patch every app on my machine because I need to change or add a fix for AutoCAD's inconsistencies. I want to fix it in one place. The only other sane way to do this is with a local Nuget server. Overkill much?

Comment: This would be very useful in order to reference DLLs from a third-party SDK that is always installed to a known location.  Even if all developers have the same folder location and structure, TFS build server will not, so sometimes absolute references are the best way to ensure that the DLL SDK repository can be located.

Comment: 2016 and this is still a problem. Now we have NuGet.  If you share a project between solutions, the relative hint path only works in one solution.  Then if you update it to be absolute and the update the NuGet package, it's relative again.  We set our NuGet cache using nuget.config so we have a known absolute starting path for all NuGet references.

Answer (score 14):

This is an old question, but it is still relevant. I stumbled upon it while searching for a solution how to reference assemblies from a global repository of third party software.

My approach at the moment is similar to the answer written by thinkOfaNumber. Instead of using a hardcoded absolute path, I prefer embedding an environment variable into the .csproj file. The environment variable then holds the absolute path. Example:

```
<Reference Include="Foo">
  <HintPath>$(THIRDPARTY_ROOT)\foo\3.1.0\bin\foo.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

This additional level of indirection gives the flexibility to have different paths on different build machines (e.g. developer system vs. build server).

I still need to manually edit the .csproj file to do this, though.

Comment: Yes, your answer is the one that truly gets to the point.  It's silly to argue about who gets to make the call on what the path is, and whether relative paths or absolute paths are the best call.  The reality is that whether you can assert all developers have the same setup or not (NOT!), the build server itself is likely to be set up differently.  If you don't use variables in your hint paths then you just aren't doing this in a very sophisticated or flexible manner.  That said, Microsoft needs to make it intuitive so that project or environment variables can be defined to hold this data.

Comment: Microsoft should also allow multiple HintPath elements so that it will iterate through them until it finds a match.  In fact, I assumed based on the word "hint" (if you give someone a hint, and it doesn't help, you probably should give them another hint... "hint-hint") that this would be allowed, and only found out through much troubleshooting that it only cares about the last HintPath element it finds!

Comment: Keep in mind that VS caches paths to the referenced assemblies in `.suo` file. So, if you change the value of THIRDPARTY_ROOT env variable, don't forget to close the solution and remove `.suo` file, then re-open the solution.

Comment: I agree that environment variables are the correct solution here. My issue was setting the path to a third party library that is on a different place on my workstation to on my jenkins machine

Answer (score 7):

By default, Visual Studio uses relative references when the reference is initially added, because it assumes that the reference is to a file elsewhere in your working copy.

This used to drive me nuts, but I solved it in three different ways:

1. By keeping my source code on my D: drive, meaning that DLLs referenced on the C: drive could not be stored with relative paths.
2. By persuading the powers-that-be to use a single image/script for all of the developer workstations. Now that they're all the same, the files are all in the same place on the C: drive.
3. By realising that you can add folders to the [`AssemblyFolders` registry key](https://stackoverflow.com/a/238445/1507899), meaning that you no longer have to use paths of any kind to reference known assemblies.

Comment: Yar, putting it on another drive, or something mapped as another drive  seems like the only way to defeat this.

Comment: Close enough, yes.

Answer (score 7):

The only way I have found to do this is by editing the csproj file manually after adding the reference.

```
<Reference Include="foo, Version=1.2.3.4, Culture=neutral, ...">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>C:\absolute\path\foo.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

and yes, I hate absolute paths and all the automatic deployment madness it creates, but in this case I have to reference a .NET wrapper that uses a COM dll that has to be "installed" and do things to the registry, etc. so an absolute path is the only way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Try right clicking the properties of the project, and then going to Reference Paths, and adding the hard coded paths there.

Comment: I did this, but it doesn't appear to actually change anything in the .csproj file.  So, wouldn't this have to be added on each dev/build machine?

Answer (score 0):

We also ran into this issue.  We wanted to use absolute paths because each deployment created the Packages folder in different locations (and we also have multiple build machines).  The idea was to have the NuGet packages in one place, which would free up the wasted memory from having multiple copies of the same thing.

Our specific problem was that we could set the absolute path in the NuGet.Config file, the NuGet packages would restore to that location during a deployment, but then it couldn't find them all during the MSBuild step *in the same deployment.*

I wrote a PowerShell script to address this issue.  It basically replaces the relative HintPath references with the absolute path that I want to use.

```
#Get list of all csproj files in a solution
$dir = Get-ChildItem $pwd -Recurse
$list = $dir | Where {$_.extension -eq ".csproj"}

#Replace relative paths with absolute path
$absolutePath = 'C:\absolute\path\Packages'
function replaceRelativePath($line){
    if($line -match '<HintPath>[^C].+\\Packages')
    {
        $relative = $matches[0] -replace '\\','\\'
        return ($line -replace "$relative", "<HintPath>$absolutePath")
    }
    else
    {
        return $line
    }
}

#Updating files
Foreach($file in $List)
{
    (Get-Content $file.FullName)| ForEach-Object{replaceRelativePath($_)} | Set-Content $file.FullName
}
```

We set this script to run as a PowerShell build step before the MSBuild steps in our deployment. The result is that the csproj files are changed for the working directory on the build machines but not in Visual Studio source control. (If you wanted them to change in source control you could probably run this in PowerShell and check in the changes.)

Answer (score 0):

Now a days with respect to new Visual Studio package management named as PackageReference there is no need to the Package folder it most cases, but this solution does not applied to ASP.Net yet and packages directory for each solution occupied Significant disk space for each solution in each developer computer in company.

So we decided to have single package directory in each computer for all solutions on it and do it as follows:

1. Each developer create a directory in one of his machine's drives.
2. Point a virtual driver letter to that place by using this registry code:

Like this:

```
REGEDIT4  
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\DOS Devices]
"Z:"="\\??\\D:\\PakcageSpace"
```

(Of course it could be done with subset command in CMD but it is not persisted and removed after restart. If it's not clear enough, I described it here:
[Cannot subst local drives as administrator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30586011/cannot-subst-local-drives-as-administrator/69880818#69880818))

3. Edit NuGet.Config in %Appdata%\NuGet\NuGet.Config and add option to it in *configuration* area

Like this:

```
<config>
    <add key="repositoryPath" value="Z:\NuGet" />
</config>
```

4. Close and reopen all solutions
5. Reinstall all packages in nuget console for each solution: Update-Packages -Reinstall

So now all packages path changed in .csproj to newly absolute path and it will be consistent for all developers machines

6. Push changes to source control

*Note: if you don't use seprate drive letter to do this, the NuGet behavior might be different in each machine due to its prefer setting to use relative path.
For example assume two different developer working on same solution on their machine  and *repositoryPath* is set to *C:\PackageSpace* in both machine

Now if Dev#1 placed workspace in C:\Workspace\CompanyCRM
And Dev#2 placed workspace in D:\Workspace\CompanyCRM

NuGet generated path for packages after Update-Package in .csproj file HintPath will be something like this:

Dev#1:

```
..\..\..\PackageSpace\packages\EntityFramework
```

Dev#2:

```
C:\PackageSpace\packages\EntityFramework
```

Now each time they pull the project, Visual Studio could not find path, restore to new path, change path in .csproj and they always have conflict in push and pulls because of changes in .csproj file.

Answer (score -2):

I would like to help but why is this necessary? I have never had to do this ever - since vs.net beta 2003. I think there is another deeper question here.

If you must you can try the Reference Path page in the project properties

Comment: Usually, this happens when someone else loads a project into a solution, in a different path depth than it was originally created.

Comment: I have led .net teams for years and you will go #@#$ nuts this way. This is the first thing I fix. Get everyone to bite the bullet and organize your solution project and references an cut off anyone's {beep} who {beep}s with it.

Comment: Well, that explains why you have never had to do this then.

Comment: You have to ask yourself why are hard coded references not easily accomplished? MS did us a favor! Because in a team environment you use source control. It is more important that everything work relatively below your workspace folder. Then everyone can have different paths to their specific workspace. It is really not that hard. Continuous integration and deployment are also much easier as well.

Comment: Not an actual answer, is it? If you are willing to discuss the question, a comment would be more appropriate.