# Cannot subst local drives as administrator

Tags: windows

For years (under both Win XP and Win 7) I have mapped S: to the local folder containing my source code by using a .cmd file in my user startup programs folder, which contains a command like:

```
subst s: C:\MyStuff\Programming\Source
```

Because I am now writing some code in Visual Studio that makes changes to the registry, Administrator permissions are required. If I don't run the above command as an administrator, the S: drive will disappear when I run Visual Studio as an administrator.

All attempts to run this existing .cmd file as administrator have so far failed, and the only attempt that looked like working explicitly requires the Administrator password. Is there a way to run subst commands as administrator automatically each time I log in without having to know/provide the administrator password?

Answer (score 1):

Create a shortcut to the batch file.

Right-Click on it and select Properties.

On the Shortcut Tab, click Advanced.

Check the box to Run as Administrator.

Use the shortcut to launch the batch file. (Or put it in your start up folder.)

Comment: Please try it and confirm it works. This is one of the options I tried previously. It didn't work for me. I also right-clicked, went to compatibility, and found that the Run As Administrator option was greyed out.

Comment: Just in case I made some obvious error, I tried this again - the advice is also found at http://superuser.com/questions/788924/is-it-possible-to-automatically-run-a-batch-file-as-administrator. Once again, the shortcut I created silently ran... and silently failed. Is there perhaps something special about subst?

Comment: Are you an admin of the local PC?

Comment: Usually, but not always - at work they like to keep administrator accounts to a minimum. In this case, no.

Comment: Okay, this only works to bypass UAC.  It can't gave you rights you don't already have.  If this is a development PC then Admin rights are required.

Comment: Well that's weird, because I can run Visual Studio as administrator without supplying a password. "What's the difference?"

Comment: I don't know.  Can you Right-Click your batch file and Run as Administrator?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79380/discussion-between-omatai-and-lance).

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution to have persist drive from path:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SUBST

The registry key solution is useful both for single user and machine wide need.

In Summary:

Save below text (with your intended drive letter and path) in a txt file, change its extention to `.reg` and run it as administrator

REGEDIT4:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\DOS Devices]
"Z:"="\\??\\D:\\Mount\\db"
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Also, you need to restart Windows for this change to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

Tries to run the command both without administrator privileges and with privileges. Runs the command twice.

I create a .bat file and run it first by myself and then through a link set to run as an administrator